# Flutter - add together the number of SwitchListTile = true

Tags: flutter

I have an app I'm working on.  It sounds simple in theory of what I want to do, but just cannot make it work.

I want to output Text of how many of the SwitchLiStTile's are true.  There are 8 SwitchListTiles, if someone clicks the 3rd and 5th ones, I want the output to be 2.  I cannot grasp how I would accomplish this.  Everything I have tried has failed.  If I could just make the value of the Switch an integer, this would be simple.

```
removed 1st example code
```

Granted, if there was truly on 2 switches, this would be way easier.  There are 8 (4 in this example) and will be more.  This is just shorthand code because I felt I needed to put something.  How would I go about getting this solved?  I have tried converting the Bools to integers and that just adds more problems.  I Can't just use a Dart Operator to add them together when they are not integers anyways.  Nothing seems to work without writing line after line, within a HUGE if statement.  I'm working with 8 switches which give a huge number of possibilities.
Any help would be awesome.

*** OK so I am going to add some simple code and try and explain what I am doing and what I want.
I'll go ahead and add the 3 files I'm using.

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'result.dart';
import 'data.dart';

void main() {
runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'TestApp',
  theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
  ),
  home: const MyHomePage(),
);
}
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
int cluecounter = 0;

final wat = [
false,
false,
false,
false,
```

];

```
final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
final _user = User();
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('TestApp'),
  ),
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
    child: Builder(
      builder: (context) => Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text('Just A Test'),
              SwitchListTile(
                  title: const Text('SwitchListTile 1'),
                  value: _user.wat1,
                  onChanged: (bool val) {
                    return setState(() {
                      if (_user.wat1 == true) {
                        cluecounter--;
                      } else {
                        cluecounter++;
                      }
                      _user.wat1 = val;
                    });
                  }),
              SwitchListTile(
                  title: const Text('SwitchListTile 2'),
                  value: _user.wat2,
                  onChanged: (bool val) {
                    return setState(() {
                      if (_user.wat2 == true) {
                        cluecounter--;
                      } else {
                        cluecounter++;
                      }
                      _user.wat2 = val;
                    });
                  }),
              SwitchListTile(
                  title: const Text('SwitchListTile 3'),
                  value: _user.wat3,
                  onChanged: (bool val) {
                    return setState(() {
                      if (_user.wat3 == true) {
                        cluecounter--;
                      } else {
                        cluecounter++;
                      }
                      _user.wat3 = val;
                    });
                  }),
              SwitchListTile(
                  title: const Text('SwitchListTile 4'),
                  value: _user.wat4,
                  onChanged: (bool val) {
                    return setState(() {
                      if (_user.wat4 == true) {
                        cluecounter--;
                      } else {
                        cluecounter++;
                      }
                      _user.wat4 = val;
                    });
                  }),
              Text(
                'counter value: $cluecounter\n',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
              FloatingActionButton.extended(
                backgroundColor: const Color(0xff364976),
                foregroundColor: const Color(0xffffffff),
                onPressed: () {
                  final form = _formKey.currentState;
                  form?.save();
                  _user.save();
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => 
Result(user:this._user),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                label: Text(' Save'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
 );
}
}
```

result.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'data.dart';

class Result extends StatelessWidget {
User user;
Result({Key? key, required this.user}) : super(key: key);


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text('Results'),
  ),
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        const Text('THE RESULTS'),
        if (user.wat1 == true)
          const Text(
            'Switch 1 is True',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
          ),
        if (user.wat2 == true)
          const Text(
            'Switch 2 is True',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
          ),
        if (user.wat3 == true)
          const Text(
            'Switch 3 is True',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
          ),
        if (user.wat4 == true)
          const Text(
            'Switch 4 is True',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
          ),
        Text('\n\nSwitch Count >>   I WANT THE COUNT HERE   <<'
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
 );
}
}
```

and the models
data.dart

```
class User {

bool wat1 = false;
bool wat2 = false;
bool wat3 = false;
bool wat4 = false;

save() {}
}
```

On the results, I want to see a count of how many switches are true.

Comment: Anyone?? So far I am still working on this and yet have found a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 0):

use a List:

```
final listCng = [true/false] // 8 value default;
```

**Code:**

```
final listCng = [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false];

return ListView.builder(
    itemBuilder: (context, index) => SwitchListTile(
        title: const Text('Switch One'),
        value: _user.wat1,
        onChanged: (bool val) => setState(() {
              // option value 3 || value 5
              if (index == 2 || index == 4) {
                listCng[index] = val;
                return;
              }

              // option other
              listCng[index] = val;
            })));
```

Comment: Thank y'all for your feedback, I gave a small example code that accomplishes pretty much the same thing.  Your examples, I could not get to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the data in GestureDetector and have a `count` variable which is updated onTap.

```
bool cng1 = false;
bool cng2 = false;
int count = 0;

GestureDetector(
  onTap: () => count++,
  SwitchListTile(
    title: const Text('Switch One'),
    value: _user.wat1,
    onChanged: (bool val) =>
    setState(() => cng1 = val)),
)
```

If the number is supposed to be displayed in the UI in reactive manner, you can wrap the `count++` in a `setState`.

Comment: Mudassir, I implemented a increment and decrement with an if statement, A new problem has risen thou.  I can get it to count up on the screen that it is on.  However, I want to to populate the count on the result.dart screen,  Notes attached within the sample app code that is attached.  I'm just stuck.

Comment: @FQHRFrenzy You would need a state management tool like provider or BLoC